# How to find current folder size in linux

Tags: linux, command

When I type `df -h` it shows a folder of size 200GB, but when I try to find the size of any of the sub-directories by `du -sch /path` the folder size is 10kB. I know that certain sub-folder should be of size 100GB.
How do I find the size of the current folder/directory in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `du -sch /abc` it doesn't show the size of hidden files (the files/directories that have the prefix dot(.) in their names) in the `abc` .

To check the size of all the files you can run, assuming you are in the directory `abc`

```
for i in `ls -a`; do du -sh $i ; done | sort -h
```

This will also sort the list.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `du -sh *` , this will give you the size of all the directories, files etc in the `pwd` in a readable format (you can get rid of the `*` if you wish obviously to get the size of *just* the `pwd`).
Read [`man du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) , also [this](http://labtestproject.com/linuxcmd/du_command.html) has some very nice examples.

Comment: I always use `du -hd1` for the size of all folders. `-d2` give also the first level subfolders etc. `-h` makes it human readable (as you already know).